# LateInitializationError: Field '_state@276051772' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to view markers when the zoom of the map is >9 but i get the error as the title, you can try out the code.  I have a work around for this, but i just want to understand how do i fix this ?

I am using the `flutter_map` package and nothing more just a simple demo to check

```
class OnTapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = 'on_tap';
  const OnTapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  OnTapPageState createState() {
    return OnTapPageState();
  }
}
class OnTapPageState extends State<OnTapPage> {
  static LatLng london = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
  late MapController _mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mapController = MapController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final markers = <Marker>[
      Marker(
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        point: london,
        builder: (ctx) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              content: Text('Tapped on blue FlutterLogo Marker'),
            ));
          },
          child: const FlutterLogo(),
        ),
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('OnTap')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Column(
          children: [
           Flexible(
              child: FlutterMap(
                mapController: _mapController,
                options: MapOptions(
                  center: london,
                  zoom: 5,
                  maxZoom: 5,
                  minZoom: 3,
                ),
                children: [
                  TileLayer(
                    urlTemplate:
                        'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                    userAgentPackageName: 'dev.fleaflet.flutter_map.example',
                  ),
                  if (_mapController.zoom > 9) MarkerLayer(markers: markers),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is here  `if (_mapController.zoom > 9) MarkerLayer(markers: markers),`

Comment: Check the [documentation here](https://docs.fleaflet.dev/usage/controller#usage-in-initstate). Maybe you try to access the map controller before the map is built. Try the usage options detailed there.

Comment: Thanks... dont know how i missed that ..

Answer (score 0):

the answer

```dart
class OnTapPageState extends State<OnTapPage> {
  late final MapController mapController = MapController();
  double? zoom = 0;
  static LatLng london = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      zoom = mapController.zoom;
    });
  }
  void _viewMarker(MapEvent position) {
    setState(() {
      zoom = position.zoom;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final markers = <Marker>[
      Marker(
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        point: london,
        builder: (ctx) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(ctx).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
              content: Text('Tapped on blue FlutterLogo Marker'),
            ));
          },
          child: const FlutterLogo(),
        ),
      ),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('OnTap')),
      drawer: buildDrawer(context, OnTapPage.route),
      body: Flexible(
        child: FlutterMap(
          mapController: mapController,
          options: MapOptions(
            onMapEvent: (p0) {
              _viewMarker(p0);
            },
            center: LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
            zoom: 3,
            maxZoom: 9,
            minZoom: 3,
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate:
                  'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
              userAgentPackageName: 'dev.fleaflet.flutter_map.example',
            ),
            if (zoom! >= 5) MarkerLayer(markers: markers),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```